# Is a C99 complex type binary compatible with a structure with two members?

Tags: c, c99, complex-numbers

Can I use `typedef struct {double r; double i;} DC;`
as a binary compatible data type for C99 `double complex` type?

My experimental C code works in my case (gcc / x86-64 / Linux). But **is this universally valid**?

```
/* gcc -o test test.c (WORKS) */
/* gcc -O3 -march=native -o test test.c (WORKS with volatiles) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

typedef struct {
    double r;
    double i;
} DC;

int main()
{
    /* var */
    const int N = 3;

    volatile DC *c = malloc(N*sizeof(DC));

    volatile double complex *z;
    z = (double complex *) c;

    int i;

    /* init */
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
       c[i].r = (double) i+1;
       c[i].i = (double) (i+1) * 10;
    }
    z[1] = -0.1 -0.2*I; // THE POINT IS HERE

    /* results */
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    printf("i = %d, c[i].r = %f c[i].i = %f\n", i, c[i].r, c[i].i);

    /* end */
    free((void*) c);

    return 0;
}
```

The program's output is here:

```
i = 0, c[i].r = 1.000000 c[i].i = 10.000000
i = 1, c[i].r = -0.100000 c[i].i = -0.200000
i = 2, c[i].r = 3.000000 c[i].i = 30.000000
```

Comment: Assuming there is no other way to do this, you might want to add several static assertions to test that `sizeof`/`alignof`/`offsetof` of these types and their members match. It's not perfect guarantee, though.

Comment: @user694733: A more important question is whether gcc and clang can be relied upon to recognize potential aliasing between c[i] and z[i].  Unfortunately, there's no way to test for that.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern I have found most reliable for testing whether gcc will recognize aliasing between two types is exemplified by:

```
#include <complex.h>
typedef struct  { double r,i; } d2;

double test(double complex *cd, d2 *dd)
{
  if (dd->r)
    *cd = 1.0;
  return dd->r;
}
```

The generated code for gcc 7.1 is

```
.LC1:
        .long   0
        .long   1072693248
        .long   0
        .long   0
test:
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        ucomisd xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        jp      .L4
        je      .L1
.L4:
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rdi], xmm1
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR .LC1[rip+8]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rdi+8], xmm1
.L1:
        rep ret
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   0
```

The return value of the function is in xmm0, which is loaded from dd->r
and tested against zero.  If it's non-zero, code stores a new value to
*cd, but does not reload the value in xmm0.

I'm not sure for what purpose the authors of the Standard specified how complex numbers are stored given that they did not in turn make them alias-compatible with anything else, but gcc attaches more importance to the fact that the Standard doesn't mandate that it recognize aliasing than to the fact that being able to alias layout-compatible types is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my copy of the C11 standard says (I assume C99 says the same):

> Each complex type has the **same representation and alignment
>   requirements as an array type containing exactly two elements of the
>   corresponding real type;** the first element is equal to the real part,
>   and the second element to the imaginary part, of the complex number.

Assuming no padding is added between or after members (as it most likely will not be), your `struct` is binary compatible with `_Complex double`.

Obviously the keyword is "assuming" which implies not universally valid. Hence the above text from the standard.

If you want universally valid, you'd want to use:

```
double val[2]; // double _Complex
```

Comment: "Assuming no padding" != "universally valid"  The question your answer implies is, "Can no padding be universally assumed?"

Comment: @AndrewHenle I thought that was implied by my answer. Provided some explanations.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful! However, **I may need to know if there is rally no padding within the structure** (on all platforms...) so that I can use the structure instead of the array. (The reason for it is that I want to use the C99 complex types in vala and it seems that I can only interface it as structures)

Comment: @DeiDei It may be - I'm trying to think it through. The assumption *feels* correct, because if a structure is padded to a specific alignment because of platform restrictions on a hypothetical platform, array elements would need to be similarly aligned for the same reasons.

Comment: In modern C, the fact that two types are layout compatible does not imply that a pointer to one may be used to access the other.  Unless there is something that would expressly grant an exemption from aliasing rules for a structure like the above, I would not trust gcc or clang to process the above code usefully except in `-fno-strict-aliasing` mode.